# Javascript target only clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have a side navigation that has a sub-menu in some of the list, and I'm trying to display the sub-menu only when it's clicked.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="main-menu" onclick="dispDrop()"><a href="">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="main-menu" onclick="dispDrop()"><a href="">Item 4</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is its CSS

```
.nav ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
}
.nav li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const navItem = document.querySelector('.main-menu');

    function dispDrop() {
        navItem.classList.toggle("active");
    }
</script>
```

At first it was working fine, but when I added a submenu to another list, it started glitching and won't display the submenu.

Is there a way to target only the clicked `<li>` and only add/toggle the class to that clicked `<li>`?

Comment: Yes, listen the click event on `ul` element. In the listener the clicked `li` will be `e.target.closest('li')` (this is called [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/1169519)). See also how to properly [add event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is adding `this` to `onclick="dispDrop()"`

And then do the following.

```
function dispDrop(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function dispDrop(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.nav ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav li.active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="main-menu" onclick="dispDrop(this)"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="main-menu" onclick="dispDrop(this)"><a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some issues that I have Identified are listed below.

- You are setting `navItem` as `document.querySelector('.main-menu')`. This will always returns the first DOM element with that class name. Not your required target.
- Your click event will be triggering the click event of the anchor tag, that will result in reload of page.

I have fixed that by toggling the class list of the target elemet from the click tiggered. This will give the required target where the click is triggered.

Call `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` inside the click event to stop the click event triggering the anchor tag click event.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function dispDrop(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active");
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.nav ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav li.active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="main-menu" onclick="dispDrop(event)">
      <a href="">Item 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 11</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="main-menu" onclick="dispDrop(event)">
      <a href="">Item 4</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 12</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite a little bit your code. The problem occurs from the anchor. You can

1. remove the anchor an style the li tag to have the anchor feeling (cursor: pointer; etc) or
2. you add a `#` to your href. that will avoid to follow the link

Then I pass with your onclick event the currecnt clickent object. Then you eventHandler knows which element was clicked.

```js
     function dispDrop(event) {
       event.querySelector('ul').classList.toggle("hide");       
    }
```

```css
.nav ul {    
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="main-menu" onclick="dispDrop(this)">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu hide">
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="main-menu clicki" onclick="dispDrop(this)">
            <a href="#">Item 4</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu hide">
                <li><a href="#">Sub-item A </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```